# How do I connect the different containers in a microservices architecture with an api gateway?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, microservices, kong

We are working on a microservice oriented architecture. As of now, we have implemented the several services using docker and spin them up using docker-compose. our architecture looks something like this: [image: architecture]

Usermanagement and tasks services are express.js servers that communicate with their respective mongodb (everything works fine on themselves). usermanagement service keeps the details of the users while tasks keeps track of tasks of the users.

Our challenge is figuring how to bring them together, how do we configure the routes? How does the frontend and backend communicate behind the gateway? (How do the services communicate with each other?) How does the client get logged in through the usermanagent downstream then authorized to access tasks? Does kong authorization plugin depend on usermanagement authorization token?

kindly advice

Comment: In our own design the front-end would use a custom API Gateway that we put in front of our microservices our websites/mobile/other devices communicate to. Similar to what you have already for your "Client".  Using your chart I assume it would be `Client -> Kong Gateway -> New Custom API Gateway -> Microservices` and `Frontend -> New Custom API Gateway -> Microservices` - Something like that?

Comment: @cer, Kindly assist me with this. Thank you.